# How to use Drawer in react native proper way?

Tags: javascript, react-native

It makes on App.js page

```
const MyApp = createDrawerNavigator({
    Requester: {
        screen: Requester,
    },
    Forgot: {
        screen: Forgot,
    },
});
```

I want to show a Welcome page with a menu button on it. When user clicks the menu button a drawer menu should appear.

```
<View style={{marginTop:30, justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 
    '#095473', paddingLeft: '80%', flexDirection: 'row' }}>

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
        {this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen'); } }>
        <Icon
            name="menu"
            size={60}
            color="white"
            //onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Register")}
         />
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

But Drawer was not open why ? please guide

Comment: what version of `react-navigation` do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume you are using recent `react-navigation`, because you use `createDrawerNavigator` function. Based on the latest doc, they replaced the previous API with the newer one. [See here](https://reactnavigation.org/blog/#drawer-routes-have-been-replaced-with-actions)

to open the drawer, you need to use `this.props.navigation.openDrawer()` instead  `this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')`.

So the rough implementation would be like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.navigation.openDrawer} />
```

full reference how to implement it:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html